# how to add wsu timestamp in soapheader using php

Tags: php, soap, soapui, soap-client

How to add time stamp in soap header of we webservice using WS security

```
<wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-9838605A27C4E11417145138838967715">
            <wsu:Created>2015-12-29T11:26:29.677Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2015-12-29T11:27:29.677Z</wsu:Expires>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
```

I achieved so far this

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://hubc.ee.sim.dsh.cms.hhs.gov" xmlns:ns2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><SOAP-ENV:Header>
<wsse:Security SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
     <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">password=</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce>EVdTeXE=</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2015-12-29T05:24:59Z</wsu:Created>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:HubConnectivityRequest/></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Can you post your code? Also can you post expected result ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/johnkary/3006526 
I am using this class for ws security WSSoapClient

Comment: how to add keystore in php ?

Comment: I just found out its working fine but I have timezone difference and didnt  signed with keystore